# Can't get all data from the db using Reactjs-Crud-Hooks-Redux-Axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement CRUD and retreive all data and put it into a table, so the console log return undefined, so I called the payload and it's not an array and I think that's the issue maybe. I'm using redux Thunk hooks. please can someone help me to solve it

here is the code bellow :

**Component.jsx**

```
import { retrieveCars } from '../action/cars.action'
    
     const cars = useSelector(state => state.cars);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
      
        useEffect(() => {
          dispatch(retrieveCars());
          
        });
```

**cars.action.js**

```
export const retrieveCars = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await DataService.getAll();
  
      dispatch({
        type: RETRIEVE_CARS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

**Car Reducer:**

```
const initialState = [];
  
  function carReducer(cars = initialState, action) {

    const { type, payload } = action;
  
    switch (type) {
      case CREATE_CAR:
        return [...cars, payload];
  
      case RETRIEVE_CARS:
        return payload;
}
```

**Car actions :**

```
export const retrieveCars = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await DataService.getAll();
  
      dispatch({
        type: RETRIEVE_CARS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

The payload that I get isn't an array

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the payload you get is an array of objects if the screenshot above represents the payload.
Maybe you could try to refactor your code.

```js
useEffect(async() => {
  const res = await DataService.getAll();
  dispatch(retrieveCars(res.data));      
}, []);
```

Your action retriveCars could looks like this:

const retrieveCars = (payload) => {
({
type: RETRIEVE_CARS,
payload
});
};

I am not sure do you use Redux Thunk middleware in the code.

Comment: Still doesn't work Yeah I'm using Thanuk middleware. and yeah the screenshot above represents the payload

Comment: I guess you put console log inside of the `retrieveCars` function. Have you checked is retriveCars function dispatched by putting console log in the  `carReducer` ?

Comment: case RETRIEVE_CARS:
        console.log(payload)
        return payload; thats return an array of objects